# how to click the button the go to some page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, hyperlink, get

Is it possible to this?

`http://url/jsp/index.jsp?id=xxx&password=xxx`

I will include it in button, so when user click the button they go to some page also login with the id and password.

Comment: Not Clear. Explain little bit more.

Comment: Password in cleartext in a link? Now ***there's*** a good idea...

Answer (score 2):

First: Putting an `id` and `password` in the page (whether in a link, in variables in code, or whatever) is a ***really bad idea***. I strongly recommend you don't do that.

---

Assuming you really want to pass the `id` and `password` as query string parameters, yes it's *possible*:

```
<input type="button" onclick="location = 'http://url/jsp/index.jsp?id=xxx&password=xxx'" value="Login">
```

...but...this is what **links** are for.

```
<a href="http://url/jsp/index.jsp?id=xxx&password=xxx">Login</a>
```

(You can style the link to look like a button if you want.)

---

If your goal is to go to that URL where access to the resource is protected by authentication (e.g., the browser would pop up a window asking for the username and password), then it depends on what kind of authentication is being used. <s>For username and password ones, then you can, you just format the link differently:</s>

`http://username:password@url/jsp/index.jsp`

*(Not anymore, thankfully. As [Jeremy Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1932079/jeremy-miller) points out below, neither [IE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489) nor [Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82250#c7) supports this (any more), and if the others haven't already followed suit, I wouldn't be surprised if they did at some point...)*

But again, it's a *really bad idea*.

Comment: Yes, such a bad idea that the `username:pass@` construct is gone (completely?) from browser support.  I've always wondered why that was *ever* considered a bright idea.

Comment: @JeremyMiller: Is it? Good! I didn't know that.

Comment: I was just researching.  Found [MS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489) and [Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82250#c7)... didn't check the others, hence my (completely?) part.

Comment: @JeremyMiller: Thanks again. Really useful information, complete with links. Doesn't get much better than that...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by this solution.

```
<button id="buttonID" link="your login url">login</button>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#buttonID').click(function() { 
        var link = $(this).attr("link");

        if(link ) {
            window.location = link;
        }
    });
});
```

Assign the id to your button and replace "buttonID" with your actual button id. In click event do the above. The url must call the login function (controller function if it is MVC) which should accepts these parameters, do authentication and redirects to the landing page.

Comment: jQuery-only answers to non-jQuery questions are not useful.

Comment: Thanks T.J. Crowder.. As agstwn21 asked this question related to javascript, this solution may helpful in case of using jQuery.